# Vue register all user activity - test tool?

Tags: vue.js, testing, vuejs2, vuex

In a couple of last months I was developing an Vue one page (almost, there's some 'route'-ing but not much) application. We are already in the end phase of alpha version and we will surely deliver it to our clients in a couple of weeks for first real live tests. But as far as I know, our end-users are just normal office people which doesn't have anything to do with programming. So if they will have some errors/troubles, they wont be able to communicate it in any helpful way. Instead they will rather say something like: *'I did this and that... I suppose... I'm not sure any more... and it stopped working'.*

So I was thinking: *maybe there's some tool which could register all user activities: mutations, events and so on (like in Vue Devtools) but maybe even more. Something that is able to, kind of 'play' it for us in a real time like a video (but still local in debug mode with the Vue Devtools on)*.

So it basically would have to work scrimba.com alike (sample: https://scrimba.com/p/pZ45Hz/c4Ny9U8).
We don't need any voice and so on. It would be enough to build some 'trouble'-button which would open a dialog box, ask for comment and sent it to us with all infos we need (vuex and events record, browser infos etc.).

Of course, I was googling this, but you know how it works. If you don't know what you are looking for, the chances you will find it are quite slight. You can find a new way of using vuex or even cooking a new type of tomato soup, but to be efficient in this particular case, I decided that joining this great community will be way better :)

If this what I'm asking about is a total fantasy, I would be also happy about some tool which is collecting browser data gets a comment and screenshot and sends it to us (like Google 'Send feedback')

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHc2u.png)

It's my first post here so if something should be done otherway I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: Try [Test & Feedback](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-exploratorytesting-web&utm_source=vsts%20XT&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=vsts%20XT%20tip) by Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your budget is, but [Mix Panel](https://mixpanel.com/home/) is a good choice. It allows you to register an event and send data to the system regarding that event.

You can use if for things like a user viewed this page, or a user partially filled out a form and abandoned it. You can get pretty elaborate on how you track.

I am not sure if there are any open-source or cheaper options. If that is out of your budget you can always search [Google for alternatives.](https://www.google.com/search?q=mixpanel%20alternatives&oq=mixpanel%20alternatives&aqs=chrome..69i57.3184j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: It sounds promising, but is it able to track a whole bunch of vuex states? We actually rather need it for tracking bugs, than checking if our 'customer' reached a goal. This is a drawing app so what we really need is sending us a complete project with log of all states leading to the final one in which possible problem occurred.

Comment: It is not intended to be a bug tracker. There are much better tools suited for that job (bugsnag, airbrake) if that is your goal. They provide the full trace and I believe they can be configured to include custom data when reporting.